# Unable to debug TSQL from unit test in SSDT

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, debugging, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools

Steps to reproduce

1.Create stored procedure under (localdb)

[image]

2.Define body and place brake point

[image]

3.Update changes to project (through schema update)

[image]

4.Create unit test (in the project menu)

[image]

5.Define unit test body

[image]

6.Debug unit test

[image]

As a result - nothing happens... breakpoint (from step 2) is not firing at all.

Output window produce next output:

```
*Done building target "SqlDeploy" in project "test3.sqlproj".
Done building project "test3.sqlproj".
Build succeeded.
C:\Users\amorozov\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Trash\test3\test3\bin\Debug\test3.sql : Deploy warning SQL72030: The project and target databases have different collation settings. Deployment errors might occur.
    1 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:07.73
Executing test script...
1 batches, 2 ResultSets, 2 rows affected
Validating scalarValueCondition1
The thread '.NET SystemEvents' (0x1938) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unhandled exception</Description><AppDomain>vstest.executionengine.x86.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.AppDomainUnloadedException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain.</Message><StackTrace>
</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain.</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
The thread 'In-proc Node (Default)' (0xcc8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1b54) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[6040] vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).*
```

The only strange thing I see in output - `<ExceptionString>System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain.</ExceptionString>`

I am able to reproduce this behavior both at work and at home.
Both systems a the same:

- VS2012 Premium (update 3)
- Windows 8 64 bit/Windows Server 2012 64bit

[image]

**Someone has this feature working?**

**What I'm doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for raising this - this appears to be a bug in SSDT and we have created a defect to track this issue. You should still be able to debug your stored procedure from a "New Query" window - see the [steps listed here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272701%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). However at present it looks like you cannot debug into the stored procedure during unit testing.